# Calculate axis limits depending on depicted data

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, plot, calculations

In a `pgfplots` axis environment, I want to make the axis limits dependent on the depicted data or some other data.

Consider the minimum working example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{table_1.txt}
    x y
    1 1
    2 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table_2.txt}
    x y
    1 2
    2 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot table {table_1.txt};
            \addplot table {table_2.txt};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to set the `xmin` and `xmax` axis options such that the offset on both sides is `xOffSet`, so

```
xmin = minimum of all x data - xOffSet * (maximum of all x data - minimum of all x data)
xmax = maximum of all x data + xOffSet * (maximum of all x data - minimum of all x data)
```

How can I do this?

And is it also possible to use other data from the table files to set the axis limits?

Comment: `enlarge x limits` options do this for you no?

Comment: @percusse Indeed, that takes care of the offset depending on the depicted data. But now the second question I posed ;). How do I do this if the I want the axis limits to depend on other table data, so data from a table file that was not (and should not be) depicted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what `enlargelimits` or `enlarge x limits` is for. If you set `enlarge x limits=0.3`, the axis limits will be increased by 30 % of the data range:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{table_1.txt}
    x y
    1 1
    2 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table_2.txt}
    x y
    1 2
    2 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            enlarge x limits=0.3,
            enlarge y limits=0.3
        ]
            \addplot table {table_1.txt};
            \addplot table {table_2.txt};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, that takes care of the offset depending on the depicted data. But now the second question I posed ;). How do I do this if the I want the axis limits to depend on other table data, so data from a table file that was not (and should not be) depicted?

Comment: @Adriaan: `\addplot [draw=none] table {table_3.txt};`

Comment: Indeed that's a way to do it :D. Quite a dirty one, but it works ;). Still, it would also be nice if you could just use expressions in axis limits like `xmin` and `xmax`. Like you can do so nicely with table data using `x expr=...`.

Comment: @Adriaan: Sorry, I missed your comment before. Could you give an example of what kind of expression you would want to use in `xmin` and `xmax`?